# Enum extensions across all enums

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have an `enum` with the following extensions:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList(this Enum en)
    {
        var list = (from Enum d in Enum.GetValues(en.GetType())
                select new SelectListItem { Value = d.ToString(("d")), Text = Enum.GetName(en.GetType(), d) }).ToList();

        var selectedValue = (int) Enum.Parse(en.GetType(), Enum.GetName(en.GetType(), en));

        return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
    }
}
```

Here's the `enum` I'm talking about:

```
public enum BillingInterval
{
    Monthly = 1,
    Quarterly = 2,
    Yearly = 3
}
```

With this `enum` and the extension it's possible for to do the following

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var vm = new CustomerViewModel();

    vm.BillingIntervalOptions = CustomerModel.BillingInterval.ToSelectList();
}
```

And now my model has a `SelectList` containing the values from my `enum`

**PROBLEM**

I've just made another `enum`, and I would suppose that this `enum` would have the same extension, but when I try the following, I get a compile error:

```
public enum Status
{
    Trial = 1,
    Demo = 2,
    Setup = 3,
    Production = 4
}

public ActionResult Test()
{
    var vm = new CustomerViewModel();

    vm.BillingIntervalOptions = CustomerModel.BillingInterval.ToSelectList();

    //This gives me a compile error
    vm.StatusOptions = Status.ToSelectList();
}
```

> 'Status' does not contain a definition for 'ToSelectList'

I'm not quite sure why one of my `enums` have the extensions but the other doesn't.

**Note:** *the second enum `Status` is not in the same file as the `BillingInterval` enum. Could this be the problem?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CustomerModel.BillingInterval` is a property which holds a value for the `enum`. `Status` is a type, not an instance.

Since extension methods only work on instances and not on types, your second statement fails.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you actually try to interact with `type` not with `enum` `object`. It should be:

```
var statusEnumInstance = Status.Trial; //here your instance
vm.StatusOptions = statusEnumInstance.ToSelectList();
```

It work in first case becouse you reference to yout `CustomerModel` property with enum object.